# Excel :Handling different date format to a standard date format

Tags: vb.net, excel

We have a requirement to handle data feeds from different sources( geographies) and load it in standard format.
Difficulty we are facing in handling excel date formats.

### We are currently using a add-in to convert the date formats, as below:

```
Private Function myFormat(ob As Range)

    If (IsDate(ob)) Then
        ' Most times a date is a date but sometimes in excel numbers that are formatted may also return true for IsDate()
        ' To avoid this case force the conversion to a number and see if it matches.  If it does then it's really a number and not a date.
        If (Val(ob) = ob) Then
            ' it's really a number
            myFormat = CStr(ob.Value)
        Else
            myFormat = Format(ob.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        End If
    Else
        If (InStr(ob.Value, ",") > 0) Then   ' we must quote any string with a comma
            myFormat = Chr(34) & CStr(ob.Value) & Chr(34)
        Else
            myFormat = CStr(ob.Value)
        End If

        If (InStr(ob.Value, """") > 0) Then     ' we must escape an embedded "'s as well as quote the whole string
            myFormat = Chr(34) & Replace(myFormat, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)
        End If
    End If


End Function
```

---

Issue : It is unable to handle date format as dd.mm.yyyy [ considering it as string ].

I have searched the forum, but could not get a definite solution using vb code.

Quick help will be highly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Swati

Comment: You have tagged this VB.Net and while VB.Net can interpret the your code, it looks more like VBA.  To get proper responses, please clarify if this is for Excel VBA or for VB.Net.

Comment: Also it appears you are converting the data to strings.  Are you trying to get out strings or actual excel dates?